# Cannot log on after I modified the .bashrc when I install the JDK 1.8.0

Tags: java, environment-variables, bashrc, jdk

I am a beginner in Ubuntu and when I tried to install JDK 1.8.0_111 on it, I modified the `.bashrc` by adding the following codes:
(I had extracted all the jdk files to the folder `jdk` under `/usr/lib`)

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jdk    
export JRE_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}/jre    
export CLASSPATH=.:${JAVA_HOME}/lib:${JRE_HOME}/lib    
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

when I typed `source ~/.bashrc` and `java -version`, it worked perfectly.

However, when I restart Ubuntu and typed in my password, it just cannot log on. So what can I do now?

Comment: Does it give you any error? Did you use quotes when specifying those export lines in your .bashrc file? I could see, if you did not use quotes, that it could possibly choke on that and fail login.

Comment: You will need to boot into text mode from there removing what you added to `.bashrc`.

Comment: Given your description, it's unlikely that the login failure is caused by those entries in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, could you shed more light on this. I thought since the last thing he did was that edit that that would be the first place to look for issues.

Comment: @George: That's a reasonable conclusion. OTOH I don't see anything obviously wrong with those entries (unless `PATH` includes folders with spaces, but it usually doesn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To permanently/temporarily take out the changes that you made to .bashrc and allow you to log in...

## If you have the root account enabled

- log into the root account
- in the `terminal` app:

  - type `sudo gedit /home/your_username/.bashrc`
  - comment out the export lines that you added by placing a `#` at the front of each line
  - save and quit gedit
  - type `ls -al /home/your_username/.ICEauthority`
  - type `ls -al /home/your_username/.Xauthority`
  - if either of the above show `root` as owner/group

    1 type `sudo chown your_username:your_username /home/your_username/.ICEauthority`

    2 type `sudo chown your_username:your_username /home/your_username/.Xauthority`
- log out of the root account
- log into your normal account

## If you don't have the root account enabled

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose root access
- at the # prompt:

  - type `sudo mount -o rw,remount /`
  - type `sudo gedit /home/your_username/.bashrc`
  - comment out the export lines that you added by placing a `#` at the front of each line
  - save and quit gedit
  - type `ls -al /home/your_username/.ICEauthority`
  - type `ls -al /home/your_username/.Xauthority`
  - if either of the above show `root` as owner/group

    1 type `sudo chown your_username:your_username /home/your_username/.ICEauthority`

    2 type `sudo chown your_username:your_username /home/your_username/.Xauthority`
  - type `reboot`
- log into your normal account